# How to display a particular clicked image from multiple image fetched from database using while loop in php, and javascript for displaying?

Tags: javascript, php, image, while-loop

I tried to display a particular clicked image(full pop-up screen when clicking image in html page) fetched from database using while loop in php but I have trouble displaying that particular image since it is inside a while loop. The result I got is when I clicked the first image I could display the first image as I want but I couldn't display the rest of the image, what I guess is that the id that I gave in img tag is accessed only by the first image. Since its inside a while loop I thought it would be okay to give the id the same but I was wrong. How do I fix this problem? I tried incrementing $i variable inside the while loop but I couldn't implement the $i inside javascript. Or is there a better way? Heres my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "accounts.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
$servername = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$passwords = '';
$dbname = 'project';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $passwords, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Could not connect... ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT photo_url FROM photo WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<span id = 'photos'>";
            echo "<img id = 'myProfile1' src = '".$row['photo_url']."' alt = 'photo' width = 190px' height = '200px' style = 'border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;'>";
        echo "</span>";
        echo "<div id = 'popUp1' class = 'pop'>";
            echo "<span class = 'close1'>&times;</span>";
            echo "<img class = 'pop-content' id = 'img02'>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<p>You haven't uploaded any photo.</p>";
}
$conn->close();
    ?>
    <script>
var pop1 = document.getElementById('popUp1');
var img1 = document.getElementById('myProfile1');
var popImg1 = document.getElementById('img02');
img1.onclick = function()
{
    pop1.style.display = 'block';
    popImg1.src = this.src;
}
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName('close1')[0];
span1.onclick = function()
{
    pop1.style.display = 'none';
}
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You are reusing element ids each time through your loop.  Elements need to have unique ids.  Especially if you are going to bind handlers by id.  In cases like this, you should bind handlers by class (in addition to assigning unique ids).

Comment: @patrick Q doesn't help

Comment: Just saying "doesn't help" also doesn't help

Comment: @PatrickQ, sorry about that, it doesn't supposed to sound rude. Was busy coding so there's literally no time for me to explain all the stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, since i haven't got a PHP setup running. But I think one way to solve this, could be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "accounts.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
$servername = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$passwords = 'root';
$dbname = 'project';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $passwords, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Could not connect... ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT photo_url FROM photo WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $i=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $i++;
        echo "<span id = 'photos'>";
        echo "<img onClick='showImage(" . $i . ")' id = 'myProfile" . $i . "' src = '".$row['photo_url']."' alt = 'photo' width = 190px' height = '200px' style = 'border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;'>";
        echo "</span>";
        echo "<div id = 'popUp" . $i . "' class = 'pop1'>";
        echo "<span class = 'close1' onClick='closeImage(" . $i . ")'>&times;</span>";
        echo "<img class = 'pop-content' id = 'img" . $i . "'>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<p>You haven't uploaded any photo.</p>";
}
$conn->close();
    ?>
    <script>
    function showImage(intId) {
        var pop1 = document.getElementById('popUp'+intId);
        var img1 = document.getElementById('myProfile'+intId);
        var popImg1 = document.getElementById('img'+intId);
        pop1.style.display = 'block';
        popImg1.src = img1.src;
    }

    function closeImage(intId) {
        var pop1 = document.getElementById('popUp'+intId);
        pop1.style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: doesn't work. Now I can't display even the first photo

Comment: I have just added a } to the end of the code - i thought it was there by mistake in your code. Can you please try again with the updated code?

Comment: Can you maybe provide us with the full code? It will be easier for us to understand i think

Comment: Thanks for the full code. I have updated my code as well. Would you mind trying it again? :)

Comment: @Fantastik so sorry to get back to you this late. Your coding actually works and Thank You for that. But I have to say this, firstly looking at your code puzzles me on how you link the two, because clearly I didn't see any $i in js and intId in php but I could understand it just now and I am very impressed with how you link the two, this thing is totally a new thing for me.  Thank You

Comment: @SangTonsing no worries at all! :) Glad it worked for you. You can actually also solve it using javascript onclicks as you did in your code. But I thought functions would be an easier solution.